# How can I put a python program with multiple files in /usr/local/bin?

Tags: python, shell, command-line

I know that if my program were just one python script file, I could just start it with the shebang and put it in /usr/local/bin so that I could invoke it at any time from the command prompt.

However, what if my program were multiple files, but I only want one to be invokable from the command line?  For example, if I've got my_program.py and dependency.py, and my_program needs dependency, but I don't want dependency to be invokable?

As I understand it, if I dump both in /usr/local/bin, then invoking either of their names will attempt to execute them... I only want my_program to be visible, but it also needs to be in the same dir as the dependency module.

I know I could just copy/paste them into one single file but that feels wrong...

Comment: See http://blog.ablepear.com/2012/10/bundling-python-files-into-stand-alone.html for instructions.

Comment: Are these dependencies imported or run as child processes?  If the are imported you only need read access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put the python files in a folder and then put this folder into an installation directory (may be in **/usr/local/foldername**).
2. Use `chdir` in script/s to change directory to the file containing folder (may be `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))`) to import dependencies from there, or use absolute path.
3. Now make a symbolic link of the executable file and put it in **/usr/local/bin**.